# Any "testing" contracts I can migrate?

Tags: truffle, private-blockchain, contract-deployment, testing

I am testing a private network and I want to test using truffle to migrate/deploy some contracts.

Is there a library of test contracts somewhere that I can use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico has a lot of good contracts you could deploy and fiddle with.  If you look through TokenMarketNet's github you can find a lot of other contracts that aren't for tokens also.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but maybe contract isn't the correct word?  I need something that I can download, type "truffle migrate" and see what happens.  I don't know what to do with the .sol files.  :(

Comment: ah sorry meng don't use truffle

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't even know there was another way.  I have a contract that won't migrate so I thought I'd try another simple one to see if it gets hung in the same part of the process.  Is there something else I can/should use beside truffle?  Would it be difficult to learn?

Comment: You could just write the code in Solidity and then compile it directly and deploy it.  I use geth to deploy contracts on the test network.  A quick guide to using the Solidity compiler and deploying to a private network is https://alanbuxton.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/first-steps-with-ethereum-private-networks-and-smart-contracts-on-ubuntu-16-04/.  If you don't have Ubuntu you can still get the gist of it by following the steps.

Comment: You are assuming I know how to write in Solidity.  Or that I know what a contract is.  Or that I am using the test network.

Comment: The wordpress article is for private chains?  If you don't know how to write Solidity code or what a contract is I suggest going to the Ethereum wiki there is a ton of info.  If you're looking for a streamlined process where you can just download a contract and run it to get a feel for the environment I don't know of that.  You could copy and paste code from the wiki's Solidity tutorial and get it running.  Best I can think of, good luck!

Comment: "If you're looking for a streamlined process where you can just download a contract and run it to get a feel for the environment I don't know of that."  That is exactly what I am looking for.  But my actual question was different and you answered that.  I have opened a new question to be more clear.  Thank you.